# Looking for solution for updating a device owner app without factory reset

Tags: android, device-owner

I have a kiosk mode Android non-Playstore tablet app (that we have been installing on the devices by using adb shell install). Kiosk mode is achieved through a combination of several DevicePolicyManager methods, setting user restrictions, and finally by setting it to be the device owner using the following shell command:

```
shell dpm set-device-owner com.dps.myapp/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

This works great and serves my client's needs well for keeping users from doing anything on the tablet other than using our app to perform their jobs. When I created this kiosk version using device owner, I "assumed" that I would be able to push future updates to the app as we had in the past (thus avoiding having to factory reset the device before each subsequent update) by using the following shell commands to stop the app, uninstall it, and then install the new version:

```
shell am force-stop com.dps.myapp
shell pm uninstall com.dps.myapp
install -r C:\\dpsworkspace\\application\\
```

Unfortunately, I've now learned that you cannot simply uninstall a device owner app, or install a new version on top of the existing one without several items being present in your app to begin with. So after much thrashing about, I've managed to code a solution to be implemented in my new version to hopefully allow this scenario to work successfully in the future, albeit it requires a factory reset before it can be deployed to the device. I'm curious as to whether I've missed an easier way to achieve this, as having to force a factory reset before installing this "new and improved" version is not settling well with the user base.

My solution includes a combination of the following:

1- adding android:testOnly="true" to the manifest, so that the device owner can be toggled off prior to installing the update

2- adding a new activity (DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity) to the app that can be started with an adb shell command that reverses some of the DevicePolicyManager settings and also performs

```
DevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

3- changing my stop/uninstall/reinstall shell commands to the following:

```
shell am force-stop com.dps.myapp
shell am start -n com.dps.myapp/.DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity
shell pm uninstall com.dps.myapp
install -t C:\\dpsworkspace\\application\\
```

This all works great, and I've tested pushing further updates past this version of the app with no problem. My question is, is all this overkill? Is there an easier way to accomplish this? My biggest worry is that I may have overlooked something that could have helped me avoid having to force a factory reset.

All solutions I have found here basically state that the current version of the app cannot be demoted to non-device owner status, because of the missing android:testOnly="true" manifest attribute and the lack of an already embedded activity to do the work that the new DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity will be doing.

I've seen a dpm command "remove-active-admin" mentioned, but that command doesn't seem to be present in any Android installation I have...besides, it requires the manifest attribute to be present in order to work anyway. Has this command been removed from the adb command set? The posts that mention it are pretty old.

Thanks for any insights you can provide. Confirmation of my "I'm pretty much screwed here right now" evaluation of my situation would also help. I hate that nagging feeling that I've missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: Its been a few years since I did it, but I was able to install a device owner over itself by rooting it, giving myself system install ability, and installing through that.  It involved using some hidden APIs in the android system.  What those were I can't remember as it was about 3 years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, rooting is not an option in our organization.

Comment: Well it seems that I spoke too soon.. my solution seems to only work on Nougat and Oreo. On Marshmallow, the uninstall still fails..... I'm now looking for anything in Settings that is different between the tablets that is allowing my solution to work on some but not others.

Comment: Further testing showed that the problem all along was with Android Studio...originally when I was testing the simplest approach, to simply install the update over the current version using the shell command "adb install -r", I was getting all kinds of adb errors related to the signing of the apk. I finally realized that after having updated Android Studio, my signed apk was located in a completely different folder, so the one I was testing with wasn't the signed apk I thought it was.Ultimately,figuring this out was key, as you CAN update a device owner app if the update apk is signed the same.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why you want to uninstall the app before installing a newer version. From my knowledge with our own device owner app, it is simply not possible to uninstall it without root access and manually deleting some xml files.

But you should be able to update the current device owner when the following preconditions are met:

- The new app has the **same package name** as the old.
- The new app uses the **same keys for signing** the apk as the old one.
- The **version code is at least 1 higher** as the one of the installed version so that the new one is recognized as an updated of the previous one.

Then you should be able to install the newer version with normal app install operations (download the APK to the device and install it via files directly on the device, from adb shell, ...).

Comment: This would work from a user perspective, but what about a developer perspective, do I have to bump the app version everytime I edit a line in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, you have to bump the VersionCode whenever you change something in the code AND you want the resulting build of the app be an upgrade for the previous released version.